# Inheriting DataContract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a `DataContract` say called `Credentials` which I've inherited into my own business object called `MyCredentials` and customized. I want to send it over the wire but understandably I get an error.

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter

Is there a way to resolve this without doing a conversion between business object and `DataContracts`? My code work looks something like this

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Credentials))]
internal class MyCredentials : Credentials
{
    public MyCredentials ()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to decorate the base class Credientials with the KnownType-Attribute.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MyCredentials))]
publice class Credentials
{
    public Credentials()
    {
    }
}
```

Also i think you need to make the class public and not internal when you decorate it with the DataContractAttribute.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyCredentials : Credentials {
  public MyCredentials () {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility modifiers do not affect a DataContract after all it is a contract.